# What does horizontal line above variable means?

Tags: notation, complex-numbers

I have a simple equation which looks like that except that there placed vector signs there are straight horizontal lines:
\begin{equation}
\ z = i^8 + \overline{z_1} \cdot \overline{z_1} -z_1 ;\\
\ z_1 = 2-3i , \\
\ z_2 = 1+i
\end{equation}

What does these horizontal lines means?

Comment: [Complex conjugate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Complex conjugate. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

In fact I do not see horizontal line but vector arrow. This kind of arrow means that variable is a vector but taking in account that those variables are complex numbers Gerry Myerson may be right that this is complex conjugate and there should be horizontal line instead of arrow.

Comment: I made them look like vectors because I could not find the right symbol.

Comment: It looks this forum supports reasonable big subset of latex symbols so you could use \overline{d} command. I have edided your question accordingly but you must accept my edit if you want change to be visible.